# How to define a multi level numbering format in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

We use a numbering format at work that looks kind of akward and it is always a pain to manually do it in word. It looks like this:

I.    This is level 1
1.1   This is level 2
1.1.1 This is level 3

II.   Another level 1
2.1   Another level 2
2.2.1 Another level 3

As you can see, the numbering of level 1, in that level is displayed in Roman numbers. But, in levels 2 and 3, it is displayed in regular numbers.

Can this multi level numbering be programed in word 2010 in order to use it automatically?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you researched and attempted so far?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Well, i have read several other posts about multi level numbering but none that actually explain how to do one like mine.